# java - таблицы данных для оперативной памяти

Tags: java, массивы, ram

Подскажите, какие типы данных есть в java похожие на таблицы Баз Данных, чтобы можно было производить поиск и сортировку данных именно в оперативной памяти. Знаю, что есть Виртуальные таблицы Mysql и Postgresql, что подходит в качество ответа, но может есть что-то более подходящее по скорости обработки.

Суть - поиск, сортировка, перебор больших данных (от 10000 строк) максимально быстро

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таких типов, и даже коллекций, не существует.
Посмотрите в сторону встраиваемых **in-memory** баз данных.

- [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html)
- [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/)